# Where is the tag table located?

Tags: ctags

I'm relatively new to emacs and currently working through the [introduction to elisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/pdf/eintr.pdf). In chapter 4 I came across the `find-tag` which should display the source code of its argument. I typed `M-x find-tag RET` followed by the argument `copy-to-buffer`. The echo-area shows the following message:

`Visit tags table (default TAGS): ~/`

but there is no TAGS file. But somewhere must be the tag tabled (default one) be installed. I run a `find` for `TAGS` on all directories but no file was found. Where is this file located?

My setup is: Debian 8.2 and emacs 24.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag table is a project-specific lookup index.  It must be generated and updated periodically.  You can use `etags` or `ctags` to do that kind of thing, I do for example run `etags *.c *.h` in `emacs/src` to index all C and header files.  The resulting `TAGS` file is placed in the same directory and needs to be selected by `M-x find-tag` for it to discover definition locations.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. however under `/usr/share/emacs24/` I just have a folder `site-lisp` with different subdirectories like auctex etc. A find for `emacs/src` was not successful. Do you know where it is located?

Comment: These are the C sources of Emacs, you can grab them from a release tarball or the Git repository.